# fetch data in react returns {}

Tags: reactjs, redux, components

I have a react component , and I want to fill its state by fetching data from the url that I tested in browser and returns json data . but in my code I got nothing, here is my code :

```
    fetch(`https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/posts.json`)
      .then(response => response.json())
    //.then(data => JSON.stringify(data))
      .then(data => this.setState({
      latitude: position.coords.latitude, // this ois ok 
      longitude: position.coords.longitude, /// this is ok 
      locations : data // here I get {}
    }));
```

Problem is here in my render function

```
const { location } = this.state.locations;
alert("1" +JSON.stringify( this.state.locations));
alert("2" + JSON.stringify( location));
```

First alert is full with correct data but second alert returns undefined.

Comment: Could you log the response?

Comment: @Claim0013 I Updated the question , please take a look at . Could you help me please ?

Comment: You are destructuring this.state incorrectly. It should be `const {locations} = this.state;`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to destructure `location` from this reponse:

```
{
  "posts": [
    {
      "_id": "5b3f761e21d434001487ad99",
      "title": "Hello Word!",
      "content": "The world is green!",
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "5b3f76b521d434001487ad9a",
      "title": "Sed porttitor lectus nibh",
      "content": "Sed porttitor lectus nibh. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Proin eget tortor risus. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Quisque velit nisi, pretium ut lacinia in, elementum id enim. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui.",
      "__v": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see, it doesn't have a `location` property so the result of your destructure will be undefined. Are you hitting the right endpoint?